# SVM image target size issue

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm

From what I can gather, when using an `SVM`, it will try to match what it was trained with to images that have the desired target in a similar size.

**Quick example to explain myself better:**

If the `SVM` was trained on images of an iPod nano that looked [like this](http://i.imgur.com/JRhDiuT.jpg), then when images that looked [like this](http://i.imgur.com/UOOaFKk.jpg) came up it wouldn't perform so well.

What I've found is that with my training set, when that it is run through the `SVM` again as the testing set, the training images that have the target shown as the iPod is (ie further away) are failed to be recognised as a match despite being trained on those very images.

So what is can be done to counter this? Or do you have to simply create multiple `SVMs` that are trained with the desired target at varying distances?

Answer (score 3):

First, your approach is not good. SVM is trying to say if the image is the same (in some size, as you said), so not if your image is containing an object in some region. So you need detect the object in the image and then classify it with the SVM. In your second image your iPod is too small, and there is too much information around it. You'll need a detector ([traincascade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEzm7L5zoZE)).

Or you can train a BOW (see [this](https://gilscvblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/bag-of-words-models-for-visual-categorization/) for better understanding), and this will be able to say if your image contains the object or not. Or try to use the feature detector, descriptor extractor and matching for finding the same object (as [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html)).

Comment: I understand and am using both `BoW` and `feature detectors`, but it is the nosier images where the target is as the iPod is in the 2nd image that are my issue. `traincascade` is something I haven't come across however so i'll definitely look into that.

Comment: For train cascade you need a lot of images... If your approach is working well (or very well) on many other images, you shall try to de-noise the image rather than go on cascades (and if you do not arrive to manage the case, then you shall go on cascades detectors)

Comment: I've implemented `Canny` to try and de-noise the images, but what I've found is that with my training set, when that it is run through the `SVM` again as the testing set, the training images that have the target shown as the iPod is (ie further away) are failed to be recognised as a match despite being trained on those very images.

Comment: ok, then your training set is not so good. As I have said, if you are training a SVM on a database that contains images of ipods like in your two images, you are inserting noise in your dataset (except if the images are annotated, and you are considering just the annotated region)

Comment: Or if you are training the svm on descriptors of features, you shall take in consideration just the features in the ipod's region

Comment: The images are striped bare of all but the exact target, ie everything is removed and left blank so its just the target in the image. But still with the smaller ones, no luck. Also, am training the `SVM` on descriptors of features fyi.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://rodrigob.github.io/are_we_there_yet/build/detection_datasets_results.html)? OpenCV bagofwords_classification.cpp is linked to this.